# App crashes showing nullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I was trying to make a basic intent from one activity to another but it crashes as soon as the button "next is clicked ".

```
    package com.example.aditya.myapplication;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private Button next;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.toNextActivity1);
            next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), qu1.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

That's the java code .
the activity_main.xml is this

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/hello"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="104dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
</ImageView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/toNextActivity1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:text="Play "
    android:layout_marginBottom="79dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/hello"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/hello" />
```

Logcat

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.aditya.myapplication/com.example.a‌​ditya.myapplication.‌​qu1}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnCli‌​ckListener)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Show logcat error

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.aditya.myapplication/com.example.aditya.myapplication.qu1}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: Do you happen to have more than one instance of the layout (for different screen densities/sizes)? If so, you need to check them all to see if the button is there.

Comment: Yea I do #theblitz.

Comment: How do i check in all of them??

Comment: But the instances are for another activity, not this one #theblitz

Answer (score 1):

Change `v.getContext()` to `MainActivity.this`

```
next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, qu1.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Does'nt help i've tried that

Comment: post your logcat...and add qu1 activity in your Manifest.xml

Comment: I've added it .. and logcat is in the question comments..

Comment: Check your qu1 layout ...also comment  Intent  and add log on onClick and check log is printed or not

Answer (score 0):

Under the

```
    private Button next;
```

write

```
    Activity activity;
```

inside

```
    onCreate(){
    activity = this;

    }
```

then inside onClick

```
startActivity(new Intent(activity,qu1.class);
```

this shud solve your problem.

Comment: It does'nt help ..

Comment: is qu1.class an activity ?

Answer (score 0):

1. May be you donot have add qu1.class activity to the manifest file.
2. Change v.getContext to MainActivity.this